# Downloading data of the currently logged in user - .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, api

I spent a good few hours rummaging around on the internet, tried various solutions, and unfortunately to no avail. The problem is that he wants to download data for the currently logged in user (his object or at least the identifier for retrieving the object). Unfortunately, with every possible solution I get null, I have no ideas what to do, and I would like to fix this problem. Any ideas? .NET 6.0 version, see title.
Hope we can solve the problem together. :)

Code:
Program.cs

```
   using KursAspNetBackend.Database;
using KursAspNetBackend.Domain.Entities;
using KursAspNetBackend.Database.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using KursAspNetBackend.Domain.Interfaces.Identity;



var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

//builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
///builder.Services.AddTransient<IPrincipal>(provider => provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);
//builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
{
    config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Adding Transients
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMessagesRepository, MessagesRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
}

app.UseAuthentication();
//app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(x => x
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) 
    .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
}



//app.Services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.EnsureCreated();

app.Run();
```

AccountController.cs:

```
using KursAspNetBackend.Domain.Entities;
using KursAspNetBackend.Domain.Dtos;
using KursAspNetBackend.Domain.Entities;
using KursAspNetBackend.Domain.Dtos;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace KursAspNetBackend.Controllers
{
    [Route("account/")]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
                                SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
                                IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getCurrentUser")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCurrentUser()
        {
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);
            
            if(user == null)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            return Ok(user);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] UserRegisterDto userRegisterDto)
        {
            var newUser = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Email = userRegisterDto.Email,
                UserName = userRegisterDto.Email,
                FirstName = userRegisterDto.FirstName,
                LastName = userRegisterDto.LastName,
                Address = "",
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, userRegisterDto.Password);
            
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(newUser);

                await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(newUser, token);

                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (IdentityError error in result.Errors)
                    Console.WriteLine($"Oops! {error.Description} ({error.Code}");
            }
            return NotFound();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserLoginDto userLoginDto)
        {
            var foundUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userLoginDto.Email);
            
            if(foundUser == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var result = await  _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(foundUser, userLoginDto.Password, true, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
               
                return Ok();
            }

            return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

lounchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:12761",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "KursAspNetBackend": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5054",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the problem well. You want only logged in user can download a file?

Comment: @afshinbr okey, so I want to create simple chat application with sign in system (to authorize only logged in users). I create register and login method and both run pretty good. After registration, new users were saving in database. While I check login method it's run well and return tokens too. I tried write this method step by step with instruction from .net 6.0 documentation with setting custom Claims and save it to cookies (I did it yesterday, unfortunelly you can't see in this code)  and it's also not working. I want to authenticate user by data saved in cookie but when I try to save it

Comment: When I try to save it I get all time null value from Claims. So when I try to get user information from getCurrentUser endpoint, I get null value in var user. I think about this line of code:

Comment: var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);

Comment: Do you have any idea, how can I solve this problem? I

Comment: You say a "simple chat application". Is this application a web page running in a browser? Or is it a separate application? If the `Login` action is returning tokens, or setting cookies, or whatever it is supposed to do, then it sounds to me like the client calling `GetCurrentUser` might not be sending the token or the cookie in the request.

Comment: It's a web page application - .net 6.0 + Angular project. Request from Angular to backend in .net seems to be send well, I get response (status 200 while login request and status 401 getCurrentUser request).